# How is it possible that you get two digit numbers multiplied by three at the beginning if you divide 1 by 97, etc.?

Tags: fractions

I divided $1$ by $97$ and I got this: $0.0103092783\dots$; I got two digit numbers being multiplied by three at the beginning.  I divided $1$ by $997$ and I got a similar thing: $0.001003009027081243731\dots$; I got three-digit numbers being multiplied by three at the beginning.  How does this happen?  It's something very remarkable, isn't it?

Comment: Now I see that you asked the earlier question. You should go back and try to understand the answer you already got, and which you accepted.  It observes that $$\frac1{98} = \frac1{100-2} = \frac1{100}\left(1+\frac2{100}+\left(\frac2{100}\right)^2+\cdots\right).$$  And if you replace the $2$ with a $3$...

Comment: Please quit terrorizing me :(